# Who did Hanß Burckhardt marry in Madelungen in 1659?

Tags: palaeography, marriage-records, transcriptions, german

Unfortunately, I cannot read the name of the woman Hanß Burckhardt married here, in Madelungen in 1659.

Can anyone make out either of her names here?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I’d say it’s “Anna Schucharten”.

It looks like there’s some additional letters right after Anna at the end of the first line, but it wouldn’t make much sense, so I guess it’s just a bleed-through from the next or the opposite page.

Comment: That agrees with my take as well.  Bleed-through for the bit after "Anna" seems quite possible - I was thinking "Kat", but that's a bit of a stretch.

Comment: Do you have access to the other page? Maybe the letters make sense there to exclude them from "this" page.